# how to implement eraser in fabric js

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, fabricjs

```js
  var width = $('#image').width();
    var height = $('#image').height();
    var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('kv_mark', { selection: false , width: width, height: height });
    var mark="";
    var i=0;
    var linex1=[];
    var linex2=[];
    var liney1=[];
    var liney2=[];
    var rightx=[];
    var righty=[];
    var wrongx=[];
    var wrongy=[];


    $('.mark-button').click(function(){
      // alert('here');
      mark = $(this).data('value');
      if(mark=='right'){
        img = "img/tick-green.png";
      }
      if(mark=='wrong'){
        img = "img/wrong.png";
      }
      if(mark==""){alert('please select a tool');}
    });
    var line, isDown;


    canvas.on('mouse:down', function(o){
      if(mark=='line'){
      isDown = true;
      var pointer = canvas.getPointer(o.e);
      var points = [ pointer.x, pointer.y, pointer.x, pointer.y ];
      x1=pointer.x;
      y1=pointer.y;
      linex1.push(x1);
      liney1.push(y1);
      line = new fabric.Line(points, {
        strokeWidth: 1  ,
        fill: 'red',
        stroke: 'red',
        originX: 'center',
        originY: 'center'
      });
      canvas.add(line);
    }
    });

    canvas.on('mouse:move', function(o){
      if(mark=='line'){
      if (!isDown) return;
      var pointer = canvas.getPointer(o.e);
      line.set({ x2: pointer.x, y2: pointer.y });
      canvas.renderAll();
      // console.log(pointer);
      }
    });

    canvas.on('mouse:up', function(o){
      var pointer = canvas.getPointer(o.e);
      x2=pointer.x;
      y2=pointer.y;
      linex2.push(x2);
      liney2.push(y2);
      if(mark=='line'){isDown = false;}
    });

    canvas.on('mouse:dblclick', function(o){
      if(mark=='wrong' || mark=='right'){
      var pointer = canvas.getPointer(o.e);
      var x = pointer.x;
      var y = pointer.y;
      if(mark=='wrong'){
        wrongx.push(x);
        wrongy.push(y);
      }
      if(mark=='right'){
        rightx.push(x);
        righty.push(y);
      }

      $("#container").append('<img class="mark" src="http://localhost:9000/'+img+'" id="'+x+'_'+y+'" style="position:absolute;left:'+x+'px; top:'+y+'px; z-index:3;width:20px;height:20">');
      //
      //        // $("#kv_mark").append('<img class="mark" src="{{ asset('wrong.png')}}" id="'+x+'_'+y+'" style="position:absolute;left:'+x+'px; top:'+y+'px; z-index:2;width:20px;height:20">');
            i++;}
    });
    $('#container').on("click",".mark",function(e){
      $(this).remove();
    });
    $('#kv_mark').on("click",".mark",function(e){
      $(this).remove();
    });

    $("#kv_mark").dblclick(function(e){

      a[i] = (e.pageX - this.offsetLeft)-17;
      b[i] = (e.pageY - this.offsetTop)-17;
      // console.log(a);
      // console.log(b);
    })
```

```css
  .correction-block{
    width:100%;
    position: relative;
  }
  .correction-block img{
    width:100%;
  }
  .canvas-body{
    position:relative;
    /*top:0;
    left:0;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;*/
  }
  .correction-block .canvas-container{
    position: absolute!important;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%!important;
    height:100%!important;
    border:1px solid #333;
  }
  .correction-block canvas{
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%!important;
    height:100%!important;
  }
  .relative{
    position: relative;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/2.4.3/fabric.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container" class="relative">
           <div class="correction-block">
             <img src="{{ asset('img/scanned1.jpeg') }}" alt="" id="image">
              <canvas id="kv_mark">   </canvas>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I implemented fabric js to draw over an image I don't how to erase on it I tried something but it is not erasing it is just adding white so my image is not showing there can anyone suggest how to add an eraser to fabric the way that it won't affect the image behind that canvas or any other approach to my problem

Comment: can please add your code to jsfiddle? it is easy for others to provide solution.

Comment: Have you been able to figure out how to implement eraser in fabricJs. I am also stuck in this problem. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It depends what kind of eraser are you talking about. In case of you'd like to create an object with the eraser characteristic (i.e. a circle or a rect) you just have to add to it the property `globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out'`.

If you want a `freeDrawingBrush` eraser, feel free to ask; at this moment this is not a feature in Fabric (version: '2.4.4') and you should hack the library to do it.

Comment: Can you help me in implementing freeDrawingBrush in Vue 3?